# Match exact text in cell with multiples values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column with comma separated values and need to find if a specific text is present. Problem is, FIND() function and related ones doesn't have a way to match exact text, so if I look for the number 1, the functions matches against 11. Any idea will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: One thing to try: use e.g. "01" instead, when you need encode "1" - i.e. fixed length on the items/tags/text you need to look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are comma-separated, just look also for the commas (and add a comma to the beginning and end of the string being searched).

```
eg:   =FIND(","&F1&",",","&A1&",")
```

Comment: Very clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find 1 and not 11 in a cell, you may use a regular expression.

As you are using comma-separated values, your regex will need to match three things:

- `1,` at the start of the text (`^` anchor), or
- `,1,` anywhere in the text, or
- `,1` at the end of the text (`$` anchor).

There is extremely comprehensive information in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/1657610) explaining how to do this in Excel.

In outline you will need to add a reference to the Regular Expressions library and write a custom function for your regular expression. You will then be able to use your custom function in worksheet formulae just as you use built-in Excel functions such as `FIND()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you format is as you have shown you can try this formula:

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(D4,FIND(",",D4,1)-1))=E4,"left",IF(VALUE(RIGHT(D4,LEN(D4)-FIND(",",D4,1))) = E4,"right",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can reasonably expect the number of entries in this cell to be below some known maximum (say, 5), and they consist of numbers like in your example (11,13):

1. Split up the column into 5 new ones, each containing the text between two commas
2. Make numbers out of the text
3. Now you can compare numbers to numbers.
   Assuming E is the original column as in your example:

The formula in the first helper column would be:

```
=LEFT(E5;FIND(",",E5)-1)
```

The formula in the second helper column would be:

```
=MID(E5;FIND(",";E5)+1;FIND(",";E5;FIND(",";E5)+1)-FIND(",";E5)-1)
```

and so on.